# android actionbar delete space

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

I make a custom android actionbar, but when I test it on my phone there is a space... How can I solve it. there is some code and image

custom_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/actinobar_logo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Homeactivity.java

```
package com.example.speakorean;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }
}
```

result Image:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gy19.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

Use Toolbar instead of using Action bar

Use Below code

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

            <include layout="@layout/lay_toolbar" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Main attribute for remove padding

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```